# Changing a colour of a cell if the data has changed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I am using a react table. I want to map through an api and if the data has changed in a cell I want to assign if a new color. I have never worked with react tables so I am not sure how to go about doing this. I want to target the individual cells .

It need to also in in a separate component and I need to just pass to the columns the component eg. Cell:  ... Will the work??

Comment: Can you provide a code sandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-lehmann-zfpxrv?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: So that's the idea, I want to assign those accessors a color, map through each cell and if a change was detected the cell should change color

Comment: And the I just want to be able to pass the Cell: <ColorCell /> components

Comment: Have you edited that sandbox? I cant seem to find the `react-table` in that cell

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-lehmann-zfpxrv?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I added a example of the table and where I want to add the Cell: <Component />

Comment: I can't seem to find the example in the sandbox you provided

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-maxwell-fjgsdt?file=/src/App.tsx